# Proper way to insert binary and varbinary datat in MySQL? Need an example

Tags: mysql

How to insert binary and varbinary datat in MySQL? Need an example

create table string_binary1 (binarydata binary(3));

insert into string_binary1 values ('a');

insert into string_binary1 values ('12343');

difference between above 2 statements, whether in both the cases data is converted to binary. If so then , it is displayed as BLOB

but if I uncheck , treat binary/varbinary as non binary charater string, then only data is displayed properly but not in binary value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simpply use quotes to insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO varbinaryt1 (varbinarydata ) VALUES('myvarbinarydata')
```

See the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html):

> When BINARY values are stored, they are right-padded with the pad
>   value to the specified length. The pad value is 0x00 (the zero byte).
>   Values are right-padded with 0x00 on insert, and no trailing bytes are
>   removed on select. All bytes are significant in comparisons, including
>   ORDER BY and DISTINCT operations. 0x00 bytes and spaces are different
>   in comparisons, with 0x00 < space.
>
> Example: For a BINARY(3) column, 'a ' becomes 'a \0' when inserted.
>   'a\0' becomes 'a\0\0' when inserted. Both inserted values remain
>   unchanged when selected.
>
> For VARBINARY, there is no padding on insert and no bytes are stripped
>   on select. All bytes are significant in comparisons, including ORDER
>   BY and DISTINCT operations. 0x00 bytes and spaces are different in
>   comparisons, with 0x00 < space.